# Laravel Cache and Unit Test

Tags: php, laravel, caching, phpunit

I use a lot the Cache system for my aplication with function like that :

```
public function active($id)
{

    $data=Cache::get($id+'100');
        if (count($data)) {   
           return $data;
        } 
        else {
          return ['No Data'];
        }
}
```

And i want to test this function.
When i look at the doc , the solution seems to make something like this.

```
public function testCache()
{
  $this->withoutMiddleware();
  $user = App\User::where('id', 10)->first() ;

  Cache::shouldReceive('get')
                    ->once()
                    ->with(10+'100')
                    ->andReturn([]);

  $this->actingAs($user)
       ->visit('/listingChoice/1')
       ->see('info');

}
```

But when i run the test it return this error :

No matching handler found for `Mockery_0_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::get("1")`. Either the method was unexpected or its arguments 
matched no expected argument list for this method

Someone know how i can test the cache like they say in the doc here :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking-facades

Any help is welcome.